# MOSEK solver on cvxpy: TypeError

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy, mosek

I am trying to use MOSEK solver with cvxpy, but I am getting:

> TypeError: keyword arguments must be strings

I've assembled a minimal example where the error still happens. Here`s the example:

```
import cvxpy as cvx

x = cvx.Variable()
y = cvx.Variable()
constraints = [x + y <= 3]
prob2 = cvx.Problem(cvx.Maximize(x + y), constraints = constraints)
sol = prob2.solve(solver=cvx.MOSEK)
print("optimal value", sol)
```

It is happening even with this very simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug. It would be good to report an issue on github.

For now, if your problem is a QP, it should work with OSQP:

`sol = prob2.solve(solver=cvx.OSQP)`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know cvxpy but you have in your code snippet 2 keyword arguments:

- `[x + y <= 3]` which is NOT a string
- `cvx.MOSEK` which is for me an unknown type

So, by your error report, at least one of them have to be a string. Try using

```
constraints = "x + y <= 3"
```

instead of

```
constraints = [x + y <= 3]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, this is the syntax for defining constraints in cvxpy. If I change it to a string I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'variables'`

Comment: So the problem is with the `cvx.Mosek`. Try `print(type(cvx.Mosek))` to assure that its type is `str`.

Comment: Yes, it is a string ('MOSEK'). It happens in long error stack. MOSEK is a external library to cvxpy. `import mosek` works. Maybe something changed in mosek's implementation that broke cvxpy integration.

Comment: So it's problem with your question as your code contains only 2 occurrences of the keyword argument. Your error report certainly contains the line number in your code where the TypeError exception occurred. Analyze that line.